# Should I make access_token endpoint as part of a REST API or as a completely new service

Tags: rest, http

If I have a REST API and I want to make my own authentication system is it appropriate to make an `/access_token` endpoint and treat it like a REST resource or should I create a seperate service for handling generation of authentication tokens etc...?

The reason I ask is this...

For a REST endpoint when you make a `POST` request doesn't the response want to contain a `link` to the resouorce so that you can `GET` it? What I really want to do is return the access token as part of the response of the `POST` request but this seems to break the paradigm of REST and would make it different from teh rest of the API, this leads me to think that the authentication should be handled by a different service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about the [OAuth 2.0 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), which never forces the separation between the Authorization Server and the Resource Server.

As for the other question, the `access_token` endpoint ought to respond to a valid POST request with a response message that contains the actual token, without this being against REST principles.

Comment: I was reading this from the HTTP spec: `If a resource has been created ... <it should> contain an entity which describes the status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location header` but I think this `The action performed by the POST method might not result in a resource that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) is the appropriate response status, depending on whether or not the response includes an entity that describes the result` But my entity can be defined by a URI so its still a little confusing.

Comment: I guess the diference in the two methods I just described are that they both contain an entity that includes the access token but the first one includes a link to the resource whereas the second one cannot. But still there is nothing saying that they both cannot contain the access token. I think that was my confusion, thanks.